# Python: Program that picks a random word from multiple text files

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI program where at the press of a button, the program picks a random word out of 3 files and displays the selected word in a Label. 
What is the simplest way that I could go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: you should try something like `createInterface(cool)`, then create a list with 3 random words with `your_list = [pickOneWord(filePath) for filePath in Folder]` and at last you can create your label with `labelize(' '.join(your_list))`. Do not forget `from __future__ import braces` at the beginning

Comment: Good luck! What did you do / think about so far?

Comment: This is a bad question as it is too broad. We haven't an idea what the files look like even.

Comment: In my way of thinking if the files are not specified, then I even have the freedom to come up with the 'simplest' way that doesn't even require a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example that randomly picks a 'word'(anything that is separated) in *some* files named `'test.txt'`, `'test2.txt'`, `'test3.py'` that are in the same directory as the below code:

```
from secrets import choice              # for cryptographically secure randomness
import tkinter as tk                    # for GUI

def random_file():
    random_file = choice(("test.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.py"))
    return random_file

def random_word(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        all_words_in_file = list()
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
               all_words_in_file.append(word)

    random_word = choice(all_words_in_file)
    return random_word

def label_rnd_word():
    global lbl
    lbl['text'] = random_word(random_file())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    lbl = tk.Label(root)
    btn = tk.Button(root, text="Random Word", command=label_rnd_word)

    # layout
    lbl.pack()
    btn.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a button in tkinter - this is pretty easy... something like:

```
    button= Button(root, text="button name", command=self.do_something)
    button.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1)
```

Import the data from the 3 text files with something like this:

```
    load_file = os.path.join('FOLDER', 'FILENAME')

    with open(load_file, 'r') as f:
        FILE1= f.read()
    f.close()
```

You could iterate this is you want, but it's hardly worth it for 3 files.

Join the 3 together....

Maybe

```
combined = string1 + string2 + string3
```

then simply select a random word

Use the random.choice() function:

```
import random
print(random.choice(combined))
```

You still need to do some work- but that's how I would do it. hope this helps!!